# Delaying An Error Message / Alert Until Two Digits Are Typed

Tags: forms, echo, alert

I have a form that allows users to input a percentage they would like to pay on a total amount. Said total amount is input within the Wordpress dashboard using Advanced Custom Fields. The form then sends the calculated total based on the percentage onto the payment gateway TouchNet.

Following is the form where where users input the percentage down:

```
<input type='text' id="percdown" />
```

Following is the script that calculates the amount based on the input percentage down (#percdown) and the total price from the ACF field (parcel_price):

```
$(function(){

    $('#percdown').on('input', function() {
      calculate();
      });
      function calculate(){
        var parcPrice = <?php the_field('parcel_price'); ?>; 
        var downPerc = parseInt($('#percdown').val());
        var perc="";
        if (downPerc < 10) {
           alert("Down Payment Must Be Above 10%");
           return false;
        };
        if(isNaN(parcPrice) || isNaN(downPerc)){
           perc=" ";
           } else{
             perc = ((parcPrice*(downPerc/100)).toFixed(2));
        }
       $('#AMT').val(perc);
    }
});
```

Following is the field that displays the calculated total, as well as the submission button:

```
<input type='text' id="AMT" name="AMT" readonly="" />               

<input name="SubmitBtn" type="submit" class="detailButton" id="SubmitBtn" value="Proceed">
```

I've used the following script to disable the submit button when #percdown is less than 10:

```
$('#percdown').change(function() {  // When value of total one is changed
  if ($('#percdown').val() > 10)
        $("#SubmitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
  else
        $("#SubmitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");      
  }

);
```

As you can see I have enabled an alert that reads "Down Payment Must Be Above 10%" if they enter a number in #percdown lower than 10, but this brings up a slight problem: **when someone types the first digit, i.e. "1", the alert pops up. Is there a way to disable this alert until they type TWO characters?**

Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 0):

The first script below calculates the total based on the ACF pricing field in the WordPress dashboard and the percentage input by the user:

```
    $(function(){

        $('#percdown').on('input', function() {
         calculate();
        });
        function calculate(){
            var parcPrice = <?php the_field('parcel_price'); ?>; 
            var downPerc = parseInt($('#percdown').val());
            var perc="";
            if(isNaN(parcPrice) || isNaN(downPerc)){
                perc=" ";
               } else{
                perc = ((parcPrice*(downPerc/100)).toFixed(2));
               }

            $('#AMT').val(perc);
        }
    });
```

This second script disables the submit button unless the percentage is between 10 and 100, and doesn't display the alert until someone has moved the cursor to the next field (tab or click outside):

```
    $('#percdown').change(function() {  // When value of total one is changed
          if ($('#percdown').val() > 10 && $('#percdown').val() < 100 ) {
                  $("#SubmitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
              }
          else {
                  $("#SubmitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                  alert("Please enter a value above 10"); 
              }    
          }

    );
```